# How to implement an interface in an Entity using typeorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I'm using an entity "User" but I need to implement the currentMatch the user is playing so I did something like this

```
@Column({
nullable: true,
})
public currentMatch: Match;
```

Where Match is an interface with all the data I need from the match.

> ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Data type "Match" in "UserEntity.currentMatch" is not supported by "postgres" database.

Is there a way to implement my interface to the entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding `type: 'json'`

```
@Column({
nullable: true,
type: 'json'
})
public currentMatch: Match;
```

Comment: Thanks, now it does compile but it triggers this error:
`ERROR [WsExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of null (reading 'player1')`
player1 being a variable of the Match interface

Comment: Maybe the interface needs to change to represent what's in the database or vice versa `currentMatch: Match | null`

Comment: It should be the case but I'll try to look that way, thanks for your help !